# Jquery slidetoggle on document ready and browser resize

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, window-resize

I have the following code which works great apart from when I resize the browser. The code basically checks the browser size on document ready and on browser resize to determine whether the menu should be displayed.  However, on resize the menu slides up and down multiple times when clicked.  I assume it registering as resizing multiple times and therefore activating the slidetoggle multiple times.  Please see example of problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/8mLvp/2/

```
function doMenu() {

    $('.menu').slideToggle();

    if ($('.menu2').is(":visible")) {
        $('.menu2').hide();
    } else {
        $('.menu2').show();
    }
    return false;
   }

}
$(document).ready(doMenu);
$(window).resize(doMenu);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, whenever you are resizing the browser, the callback is fired and the click event is bound. So if you resize multiple times, the click event gets bound multiple times and thus the callback gets called multiple times. Just do the check for the width inside the click handler itself and assign the click handler only once:

```
$('.icon-menu-2').click(function () {      
    var width = $(window).width();

    if (width < 530) {
        $('.menu').slideToggle();

        if ($('.menu2').is(":visible")) {
            $('.menu2').hide();
        } else {
            $('.menu2').show();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work, it's the same than the problem. If you resize always under 530 then the problem is gonna be still there.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of achieving this, but using a timeout is the simplest. This will check if the user has finished resizing

```
function doMenu() {
 //your stuff to happen here
}

var TO = false;
$(window).resize(function(){
 if(TO !== false)
    clearTimeout(TO);
 TO = setTimeout(doMenu, 200); //200 milisecond check
});
```

see my example here http://jsfiddle.net/8mLvp/

Comment: I assume I am to replace 'resizeStuff' with 'doMenu'?  It doesn't seem to be activating my function with either

Comment: You need to use the slideToggle function to see my issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/8mLvp/2/

Comment: This solution worked for me, the answer marked as accepted does not make sence if you are resizing under 530px, then the problem is gonna be there still. By the way, is there another way now 2016???